# Let $H \subset G$. Let $k = [G:H]$ and assume that $k$ is finite. Let $g \in G$. Show that $\exists m \in \{1,\dots, k\}$ such that $g^m \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group with subgroup $H$. Let $k = [G:H]$ and assume that $k$ is finite. Let $g \in G$. Show that $\exists m \in \{1,\dots, k\}$ such that $g^m \in H$.

If $k$ is finite then must $[G:H]$ be finite also? That would imply that $k = \frac{|G|}{|H|} \implies |G| = k|H|$. Now since $|G|$ is finite with order $k|H|$ we have that $g^{k|H|} = e$. But since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ the identity of $G$ is in $H$ and thus $g^{k|H|}  \in H$.

I feel like this is not right... What might I be forgetting? Is it true that $k$ finite implies that $[G:H] $ is finite and thus $G$ would be finite and then by Lagrange $[G:H] = \frac{|G|}{|H|} $?

Comment: I don't see an assumption that either $|G|$ or $|H|$ is finite, so things like $|H|$ in the exponent don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since $k$ is defined to be $[G:H]$, if it is finite, then $[G:H]$ is definitely finite. Nevertheless, we have no idea whether $G$ and $H$ are finite or not, so it is incorrect to write such fraction. Consider the example $\mathbb{Z}$ with subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}$. The index is $2$ but neither one of them is finite.

You simply consider the sequence $$H,gH,g^2H,\cdots,g^{k-1}H,g^kH.$$ Since there are $k+1$ cosets here but only $k$ distinct cosets of $H$ exist, there must be some repeated terms, say $g^aH=g^bH$ for some $0\leq a<b\leq k$. Then we have $$g^{b-a}\in H,$$ where $m:=b-a\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are k elements in G, say $g_1$, $g_2$, ..., $g_k$ such that $\cup_{n=1}^{n=k}g_nH = G$. Take a g from G and consider $k+1$ elements $g,g^2, ...,g^{k+1}$. Two of them must belong to the same coset, say $g_lH$. It means that, for some p and q (q> p) $$g^p = g_lh_p$$ and $$g^q=g_lh_q$$ So, $g_l = g^ph_{p}^{-1}$ and putting this into the second equation $$g^{q} = g^{p}h_p^{-1}h_{q}$$. Now just multiply from the left by $g^{-p}$ to get that for some r = (q-p) $$g^{r} = h_p^{-1}h_q$$
This is all good if all $k+1$ elements of the form $g^n$ are different. If not, i.e. if two of them are the same then $g^m = e$ for some $m$ (as is easy to show). In this case one of course has $g^m = e$ is in $H$.